# ¿Cómo puedo refrescar la página tras volver del botón retroceso de javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una página donde se muestran resultados de una búsqueda a la api de Spotify. Los elementos que ya tengo añadidos en la base de datos los muestro con un botón de ir a ver el detalle y los que no tengo añadidos con un botón añadir. Al añadirlo redirige al detalle. Hasta aquí perfecto. Pero en la vista del detalle tengo un botón volver atrás de javascript:

```
<a href="javascript:history.back()" class="left"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
```

y al volver al listado no ha actualizado la página, para ver el item como corresponde tengo que refrescar la página desde el navegador.
He probado ponerle en el script window.reload() pero claro, entra en bucle infinito...

Necesito que al volver desde la página de detalle se refresquen los resultados del listado.

Comment: La página anterior es una url fija conocida? si es así bastaría con agregar algun parametro random. por ejemplo `window.location.href = "lista.html?random=" + getTime()"`

Answer (score 1):

Pruebe a volver a la página anterior y tener este código en la página

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    location.reload();
});
```

Comment: el OP dijo que al hacer un `reload()` entra en un bucle infinito...

Comment: No va bien, esto refresca la pagina en bucle.